# MySQL trigger does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've been trying to create a MySQL Trigger in order to set a random value to a column called `confcode` which is used for authentication purposes.

The issue is, the value never sets after I insert a new row and keeps being empty.

I use `phpMyAdmin` to create the trigger, and these are the defines:

```
Trigger name:    confcode
Table:    ebaysales
Time:    BEFORE/AFTER (both don't work)
Event:    INSERT
Definition:    SET @confcode = FLOOR(RAND()*999999)+111111
```

The trigger itself gets inserted successfully, but doesn't seem to affect anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
SET NEW.confcode = FLOOR(RAND()*999999)+111111;
-- instead of
SET @confcode = FLOOR(RAND()*999999)+111111;
```